# IE ignores absolute positioning on a ::before

Tags: css, internet-explorer, absolute

Using IE11, but looking for a solution IE9+, I'm debugging why [the labels at the bottom of this CSS bar chart are improperly positioned](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tAemu).

From what I can tell with the IE debugger -- despite the relative parent container having a definite width and height -- the `position:absolute` is not being applied to the `::before` pseudo, resulting in strangely placed labels:

```
.chart span::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
```

In Chrome, FF, etc. all is well: the labels are below the bar chart as expected.  Any insight on why this occurs, or any tips on debugging ::before in IE (I can't target the ::before like I can in Chrome and FF)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `top:100%` with `bottom:-21px` on your `::before` pseudo element.  That seems to work in FF, Chrome, and IE9+.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yegnu)

Comment: By jingo, it does!  Did you (take an educated) guess that `top` was the issue, or did you debug it in IE?  If so, is there a way to get IE debugging `::before` like Chrome and Firefox?  (That is, the `::before` is given an actual element in the DOM you can inspect, separate from the applied selector.)

Comment: @bishop I question whether 100% equates in the other browsers to 21px and that's the magic in making it work but not a solution.

Comment: I don't know of a way to inspect and highlight the actual pseudo element in IE, so I just inspected the span, which allows you to see and fiddle with the `::before` styles in the styles pane of the "DOM Explorer".

Comment: @Rob I imagine the OP's goal in using `top:100%` was to achieve a certain appearance (text on bottom).  `bottom:-21px` is another path to achieving that appearance, but with _consistency_ across his browser requirements.  If he needs to make it -20px or -22px, he is free to tweak as needed.  How is this not a solution?

Comment: @Talmid I should have said not a "proper" solution because he's using a variable top and your solution gave a fixed value. That value may work in one case but not all cases if a dynamic value is needed which is why I asked the question.

Comment: @Rob: My final use case is design-for-print, so abandoning the relative 100% in favor of a fixed value works perfectly.  I'm still curious as to why IE treats 100% this way, though.